# When I use Leaflet's layer control, I get grey image because the visibility is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, leaflet, mapbox

I am using leaflet's layer control to change the disableClusteringAtZoom when it's toggled but I get

```
<div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

for the tiled images. So I can see all the markers but I cannot see the maps when I zoom in or zoom out after changing the layer for the first time.

```
function initLayers() {
     markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
        disableClusteringAtZoom: 11
    });
     markers2 = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
        disableClusteringAtZoom: 1
    });

    geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(permData, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var bubble = //Info that goes in marker.
        }
    });
    geoJsonLayer2 = L.geoJson(permData, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var bubble = //Info that goes in marker.
       }
    });
    markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
    markers2.addLayer(geoJsonLayer2);

    //map.addLayer(markers);
    //map.addLayer(markers2);

    if (!doGeocode) {
        map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds(), { animate: false });
        map.fitBounds(markers2.getBounds(), { animate: false });
    }
}
```

and my control function is

```
function layerControl() {
    var lcontrol = L.control.layers({
        'Clustered': markers,
        'Not Clustered': markers2
    }, null, {collapsed: false});
    map.addControl(lcontrol);
    });
}
```

I call initLayers when I call $.ajax and return success. After initLayers() I call layerControl(). Am I doing something wrong? Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by updating the leaflet version to the latest.